# Parallel Optimization with matlab fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization

So I am trying to optimize 2 set parameters one for each axle of this scheme.The first set has to be optimized on delta between left and right flywheel, while set 2 is the same for the other axle

At the moment I am using fmincon and running in parallel the simulation of left and right flywheel of each axle as the cost function is the error between the two outputs.

The basic code is something like this

```
for Axle = 1:2
...
fmincon(CostFunc,InitialValues, lb,ub)
end
```

The CostFunc is something like this

```
fob = CostFunc(...)
parfor FlyWheel = 1:2
FlyWheelOutput(FlyWheel) = simulation(...)
end
fob = FlyWheelOutput(1) - FlyWheelOutput(2)
```

So instead of 4 cores I a using only 2, making the code slower than what it could ideally be. So the question is do you know anyway how to overcompe this impasse?

[Basic scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejuDF.png)

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, your code effectively has this basic structure:

```
for Axle = 1:2
    ...
    % fmincon(Costfunc, ...)
        parfor FlyWheel = 1:2
            FlyWheelOutput(FlyWheel) = simulation(...)
        end
    % end fmincon
end
```

You could [potentially speed up processing by moving `parfor` to the outer loop instead.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/nested-parfor-loops-and-for-loops.html#bvjfi19-1)

```
parfor Axle = 1:2
    ...
    % fmincon(Costfunc, ...)
        for FlyWheel = 1:2
            FlyWheelOutput(FlyWheel) = simulation(...)
        end
    % end fmincon
end
```

While I can't guarantee that you will use all 4 CPU cores simultaneously instead of 2, this could be faster, since you are executing `parfor` once outside a loop, instead of twice inside a loop.

---

If runtime is still a problem, consider using the [built-in profiling tool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) to find out which part of your code is slowest, then optimize from there.